# Use ref in Higher Order Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Table` component that I want `ref` to be attached to.

Use: *Table.js*

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rows: 1,
      dataLength: props.dataLength,
    }
    this.tableRef = React.createRef(); 
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    //using ref
    this.tableRef.current ..... //logic using ref
    this.state.rows ..... //some logic
  }

  render() {
    <TableContainer ref={this.tableRef} />
    <CustomPagination />
  }
}
```

This works fine, but now my requirement has changed, and I want to reuse the Table component with pagination applied to all the Tables in my App. I have decided to make a HOC `withCustomPagination`.

Use: *withCustomPagination.js HOC*

```
import CustomPagination from 'path/to/file';

const withCustomPagination = tableRef => Component => {
  return class WithCustomPagination extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        rows: 1,
        dataLength: props.dataLength,
      }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      tableRef.current.state ..... //logic using ref, Error for this line
      this.state.rows ..... //some logic
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Component {...state} />
        <CustomPagination />
      )
    }
  }
}

export default withCustomPagination;
```

New *Table.js*:

```
import withCustomPagination from '/path/to/file';

const ref = React.createRef();

const Table = props => (
  <TableContainer ref={ref} />
);

const WrappedTable = withCustomPagination(ref)(Table);
```

HOC `withCustomPagination` returns a class `WithCustomPagination` that has a `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method that uses Table ref in the logic. So I try to pass `ref` created in *Table.js* as argument to `withCustomPagination`, i.e curried with `ref` and `Table` stateless component.

This use of `ref` is wrong and I get error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null`.

I tried using *Forwarding Refs*, but was unable to implement it.

How do I pass the Table `ref` to `withCustomPagination` and be able to use it in HOC?

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can use [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)

It means you have to forward `ref` and specify which function or object or,...
you want to share with `ref` inside your functional component.

Here is my Hoc example :

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export function CommonHoc(WrappedComponent) {

    const component = class extends React.Component {

         componentDidMount() {
           this.refs.myComponent.showAlert();

        }

        render() {
            return (
                <>
                    <WrappedComponent
                        ref='myComponent'
                        {...this.state}
                        {...this.props}
                    />
                </>
            );
        }
    };
    return component;
}
```

and it's my stateless component

```
const HomeController=(props,ref)=> {

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({

        showAlert() {
            alert("called");
        },
    }));

    return (
        <Text>home</Text>
    );
};
export default CommonHoc(forwardRef(HomeController));
```

Comment: Can you please provide an updated answer for new React.createRef() based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Either restructure your code to not use a HOC for this or try using `React.forwardRef`:

> Refs Aren’t Passed Through
>
> While the convention for higher-order components is to pass through
>   all props to the wrapped component, this does not work for refs.
>   That’s because ref is not really a prop — like key, it’s handled
>   specially by React. If you add a ref to an element whose component is
>   the result of a HOC, the ref refers to an instance of the outermost
>   container component, not the wrapped component.
>
> The solution for this problem is to use the React.forwardRef API
>   (introduced with React 16.3). Learn more about it in the forwarding
>   refs section.

via [Higher-Order Components: Refs Aren’t Passed Through](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#refs-arent-passed-through)

In the [forwarding refs section](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components) there are code examples you could use to pass refs **down**, but trying to yank them up will fail in your case with:

> Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.

In a project we took a different approach. There's an `EnhancedTable` component that handles all of the pagination logic and in itself has the dumb table component and the pagination component. It works pretty well but this means you would have to drill props (or use a store lib like Redux or Mobx) and add new ones that will handle pagination options. This will result in some refactoring of `Table` uses and you'll have to be more explicit but I would take it as a boon rather than a hindrance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve a simmilar issue that brought me to this thread without using forwardRef or useImperativeHandle.

By creating the ref at a higher level, and passign it down into the component and sub components that I needed to act on with the ref.

```
/** Parent Component has access to ref and functions that act on ref **/

import { useRef } from 'react';
const formRef = useRef(); // ref will have dom elements need accessing

const onClickFunction=()=>{ //sample function acts on ref
  var inputs = formRef.current.querySelectorAll('input')
 /* Act on ref here via onClick function, etc  has access to dom elements 
  in child component and childs child components */
 };
 return(
 <ComponentGetsAttachedRef formRef={formRef} /> 
 //^ref sent down to component and its children
 <ComponentNeedingRef onClickFunction={onClickFunction}/>
 //^function with access to ref sent down to component
 )

/** Child component needs to act on ref**/

export const ComponentNeedingRef = ({ onClickFunction}) =>{
 return(
  <button onClick={onClickFunction}>
 )
}

/* Child component recieves ref and passes it down */

export const ComponentGetsAttachedRef = ({ formRef}) =>{
//ref comes in as prop gets attached to props or utilized internally

 return (
 <ChildsChildComponent formRef={formRef}/> //sub component passed ref down
 )

}
```